# Determine the id of the div that has been scrolled to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

simple question, easy points, cannot find the answer in SO. The javascript function below alerts when a user scrolls to the bottom of a div. I have many divs, but I only want the alert to run when a div id=imageloc is scrolled.

```
 $(window).scroll( function() {
     if ( document.documentElement.clientHeight + $( document ).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight ) { 
        if (this.id == "imageloc" ) {
            alert("bottom of the page.");
        }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The javascript function below alerts when a user scrolls to the
>   bottom of a div. I have many divs, but I only want the alert to run
>   when a div id=imageloc is scrolled.

Maybe I have misunderstood, but it's phrased like you have many scrollable divs and want to do something if one of them is scrolled to the bottom. Then you should listen to `scroll` event on this particular div:

```
$("#imageloc").scroll( function(e) {
     if ( this.scrollTop >= this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight ) { 
        console.log( 'bottom' )
     }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aheh5/

If you want to do something when the document has been scrolled past the bottom of a particular div try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aheh5/1/  (it will, however, trigger every time the user scrolls the window and #imageloc is above the viewport).

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
var $divs = $('div');

var top = $.grep($divs, function(item) {
    return $(item).position().top <= winTop;
});

alert($(top).attr('id'));

});
```

Comment: it means the div may not have an id attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
var imgLocTop = $('#imageloc').offset().top ; 
var $window = $(window); 
var limit = Math.abs($window.height() - imgLocTop); 
$window.scroll( function() { 
    if($window.scrollTop() >= limit) {
      alert('Reached the required div');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AkXUC/)**